# How to download multiple files on Chrome with Capybara/Selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I am using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) with Chrome and Selenium. When I attempt to click on a link that causes an automatic download, the file is downloaded correctly. If I try to do this again, Chrome shows the message: "This site is attempting to download multiple files. Do you want to allow this?"

[image]

I was looking for a [flag](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that could be used to disable this message, but couldn't find anything. Is there any way I can get around this message and allow the multiple download without having to resort to a page refresh? (E.g. Is there any way I can click the Allow button programmatically?)

Comment: Here's my post on how to find the right flag for your setup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36821119/4854090

Answer (score 1):

Please see my work-around here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=130#c12

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Options

```
WebDriver driver = null;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        prefs.put("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1 );
        //Turns off download prompt
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```