# Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I developed a crawler with ruby watir-webdriver that downloads some files from a page. My problem is that when I click to download the second file, Chrome opens a bar in the top asking for confirmation that I am downloading multiple files from this website.

Once this is used by webdriver, I cannot confirm the download. Is there anyway to avoid this confirmation? I am thinking if is there any configuration to avoid it or if is there an extension to do this or even if I can click on the confirmation with webdriver.

thanks

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Chrome 49 and none of the other solutions worked for me.
After some research I found a working solution:

```
ChromeDriver createChromeDriverWithDownloadFolder(String folder) {
    Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", folder);
    chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1 );
    chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    return new ChromeDriver(cap);
}
```

It seems as if these settings are constantly changing. Therefore, here's how I found the right solution for my setup:

1. Open Chrome and go to chrome://version/ to find the path of your profile
2. In *Default/Preferences* is a json file called *Preferences*. Open it and search for *automatic_downloads*.
   In my case the interesting part of the file looked like this:

   ..."profile": {
   "avatar_bubble_tutorial_shown": 1,
   "avatar_index": 0,
   "content_settings": {
   "clear_on_exit_migrated": true,
   "exceptions": {
   "app_banner": {},
   "auto_select_certificate": {},
   "automatic_downloads": {
   "[*.]localhost:63342,*": {
   "setting": 1
   },...
3. From that I could derive that the right setting would be `chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1 );`

Comment: Thanks. Given solution worked for me on chrome 51 and chrome driver 2.20.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me on the latest chrome browser and chrome driver version

Comment: it is throwing `bad_variant_access` error for me, I am using puppeteer to launch chromium & download something from website.

Answer (score 12):

**As of Chrome 56.0.2924.87, February 17, 2017**, the **only** preference you need to set (however you set them for your webdriver) is:

```
'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1
```

Giving an updated answer because most answers here use outdated preferences or show other preferences that are unnecessary.

Comment: FYI.. this setting/option is still working with the newest Chrome version i.e.Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit). Tried and tested.

Comment: this one works for me

Comment: And apparently it's stopped working :|

Answer (score 7):

for new chrome (version 46 or newer) this options was changed
now your hash must looks like this:

```
prefs = {
    'profile' => {
        'default_content_settings' => {'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1}, #for chrome version olde ~42
        'default_content_setting_values' => {'automatic_downloads' => 1}, #for chrome newer 46
    }
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs, args: ['--test-type', '--disable-infobars'}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but broke how I was originally handling browser window sizing.  Is there a site that lists ALL the changes one can make?

Comment: This solution is working in version 66 using chromedriver in selenium with perl.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution for Java - Selenium implementation

We faced hard time fixing this, as we wanted to add automation test for functionality which downloads set of PDFs on a single download link.

```java
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//To Turns off multiple download warning
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put( "profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1 );
//Turns off download prompt
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", prefs);
driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Hope this help to someone.

Comment: Do you have a javascript version? Of can I even do that from client-side using Javascript? All I need is setting multiple-automatic-downloads" to 1 (true) !! Because I do not want to see the prompt asking it.

Comment: No I dont have javascript version. Not sure but it should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the solution is different for older and newer chromedriver versions and that is adding to the confusion.

**chromedriver**

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = download_directory

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

**chromedriver2**

```
prefs = {
      'profile' => {
          'default_content_settings' => {'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1},
      }
  }

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
```

Today most people are probably using **chromedriver2** version and that is a solution that should work fine. It worked ok in my *watir* scripts as I am not getting the message: "*This site is attempting to download multiple files. Do you want to allow this?*" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Java solution:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> content_setting = new HashMap <>();

content_setting.put("multiple-automatic-downloads",1);

prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings", content_setting);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug/enhancement has been raised in the chromedriver page at the below URL:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=130

Bug/Enhancement Status: Yet to be resolved.

Comment: Did you get any solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do it on page load client-side using markups.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Disposition" CONTENT="inline" />
```

It seems to work (it is working at this moment, in overriding).

But time will tell (might not have effect on future CHROME's, you know what I mean).

There are a list of available header fields published on a couple of sites which I find extremely helpful. Hope it will help you, as well.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/content-disposition.txt
   https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml#cont-disp-2