# Python Selenium Chrome disable prompt for "Trying to download multiple files"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am currently running a Python automator which needs to download multiple files within the same session using Selenium Chromedriver.

The problem is that when the browser attempts to download the second file and read it, the browser will not download until the "Allow" button has been clicked.

I have researched the ChromeOptions part of Selenium to do with disabling it, but many of the answers were in Java, or even other browsers.

**To summarise**, how do you disable the prompt for allowing multiple file downloads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation)

Comment: Hi adrianus,  I had previously viewed this and other questions asked already, none of these answer my question though unfortunately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try passing the according preference to `webdriver`?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = Options()

# this is the preference we're passing
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# just downloading some files...
for _ in range(5):
    driver.get("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.map")

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that doesnt work either. I just have my browser click on a button which causes the download. driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="title"]').click()

Comment: Try again please, I had an error in the `prefs`-string.

Answer (score 1):

The only 2 prefs I've ever had to set are:

```
download.prompt_for_download = False
download.default_directory = "/path/to/folder/"
```

Comment: doesnt work if u download multiple files at once

Comment: That's what works for me too (Chromium 97); now I'd like to find out if there's a setting to disable the lower dowload bar from showing the downloaded file?