# Chromedriver (selenium) interrupts due to pop up: "site wants to download multiple files"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping a website with Selenium, and this pops up and then Selenium can't do anything. How can I bypass this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430532/python-selenium-chrome-disable-prompt-for-trying-to-download-multiple-files)?

Answer (score 1):

You need `chrome options` to get rid off of that.

I have these options in one of my project.

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

```
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1})
```

and then **initialize browser object** like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

the option that will help us in this case is

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just bypass the browser level popups, we can achieve thru ChromeOptions class

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
```

pass the ChromeOptions object to WebDriver

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("");
```