# Selenium chromedriver python allow multiple downloads

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selemium chromedriver with python, and I need it to download automatically large amount of files, the problem is that chrome asks to allow multiple downloads, is there a way to block chrome from asking me that and automatically allow multiple downloads?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation)

Comment: I saw this - but I could't figure out how to translate those commands to python(I am new to Selenium)