# Selenium chromedriver in python - don't ask for allow multiple downloads

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selemium chromedriver with python, and I need it to download automatically large amount of files, the problem is that chrome asks to allow multiple downloads, is there a way to block chrome from asking me that and automatically allow multiple downloads?
I already saw this two for other languages: [Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation), [Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation) however they does not work for me and it keep asking me to allow multiple downloads.

Comment: Does your chrome still ask you when you download single file? Or it only prompts on multiple files download?

Comment: Not for one file, only for multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the chrome options for the chrome driver, specifically the `download.prompt_for_download` option to false.  See the [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) documentation, here is an example:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = { 
    "download.default_directory": "C:\tmp\whatever\", 
    "download.prompt_for_download": False
    }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Selenium documentation they are not a solution for downloading things (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/file_downloads/).

They do have a solution to interact with alerts and stuff (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/).

As a possible solution you could try using Selenium in the headless mode perhaps avoiding the question in first place. I am trying it right now.

Comment: The selenium documentation you linked doesn't say there is not a solution, only that you can't monitor the download progress via selenium.  You just have to set browser preferences to download without asking and it will work fine.