# How to automatically close Chrome notifications with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an automation project, where we have a website which downloads multiple CSV files. During the download Chrome shows a notification `"Multiple Download"`.

Due to this notification, the automation stops.
I have been unable to identify notification elements.
The notification has two buttons: `Allow` and `Block`.
I want to press the `Allow` button with help of JavaScript.

Is this possible?
I am using an automation tool that supports JavaScript.

Comment: It may be helpful to know exactly which automation tool you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable chrome download multiple files confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation)

Comment: I am using automation anywhere A2019. For the timing I used image recognition action to handle such message, but I feel JavaScript will be more robust.