# How to click "Allow" automatically on Google Chrome pop-up using Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, chrome-options

Based on what I have read, there is a way to do this for Google Chrome versions < 50 and a way to do this for Google Chrome versions > 50. I am using Google Chrome 91.

There is an answer on to this located here: [How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)
which states that I need to do something like this:

```
//Create a map to store  preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// set ExperimentalOption - prefs 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

However, this does not work for me. This is what the pop up looks like [image: pop-up]

and this is how I am using it:

```
// Create a map to store preferences (to disable pop-up notifications)
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
// Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

// for local automated testing
this.chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
String chromeDriverPath = "resources/chromedriver-91.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
System.out.println("new chrome driver started.....");
this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So as you can see, I have tried multiple different ways. `"--disable-notifications"` did not work and neither did `chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);`
When I run my program, the pop-up is still there, I need to Selenium to click "Allow" on the pop-up so I can continue with the rest of the program.

Comment: Did you try with `prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);`  as well ?

Comment: Yep, tried that as well

Comment: 1 is to allow and 2 is to block notifications there, but this seems to no more working for Chrome versions >90

Comment: You're saying this won't work on versions > 90?

Comment: I have it in python for 91 and it works perfectly

Comment: Hmm then I don't get it. This seems pretty straight forward, how could this not work??

Comment: I have `options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")` and `options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")` also as a part of options, try setting that up in Java and do a refresh project and see if that works

Comment: Tried that as well and nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to download a file, which is different behavior than showing notifications. Try

```
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
```

Comment: Can we have some reference link for this  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817328/disable-chrome-download-multiple-files-confirmation